# How do I move the shape or selection while creating

Tags: adobe-photoshop

In Photoshop, how do i move the selection or shape while creating it self. is there any procedure or shortcut key to move the selected path while selecting the path itself?

Thanks very much for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When drawing your shapes there are a few hotkeys that you can make use of:

**Shift** - Constrains the proportions. This causes both the height and width to adjust equally, allowing you to create perfect squares and circles.
**Alt** - Allows you to drag a shape out from its center rather than one of the corners.
**Spacebar** - Move the shape while you are currently drawing it.

Comment: Spacebar only works with Illustrator but not Photoshop until CC